# How do i resolve this error "Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK"?

Tags: android, android-studio

Ok, so i have been using eclipse for my android development but then i noticed that the eclipse IDE gave me a lot of errors and i researched online and found that Android Studio was worth a shot. So, i downloaded android studio yesterday and then created a test application. The Target SDK was 15 and i was using Android 2.0 Froyo to test my application since it loads faster. Now, when i run my app, i get that annoying message and i have no clue how to fix it. Please guide me through the steps of fixing it. Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: You are deploying the app in to lower version than you specified in your manifest.

Answer (score 4):

The `minSdkVersion` in your project -- whether from your code or from a library -- is higher than the API level of the device or emulator on which you are trying to run your app. Either:

- Adjust your `minSdkVersion`, or
- Use a device or emulator that is capable of running Android at the level specified by your `minSdkVersion`

Comment: :- Thanks a lot for your help. Now, here is the thing if i use Android 2.0, the emulator loads fast but say if i use API 15 , the emulator takes forever to load. Please tell me a way such that i can use a higher API and the emulator doesn't take that much time to load.